# Area of intersection of a circle with a rectangle

Tags: geometry, algorithms, contest-math

I want to find the area of a given circle that comes under the region of a given rectangle. I searched many posts on stackoverflow but they are not satisfying. I followed this post
http://www.eex-dev.net/index.php?id=100
But it doesn't seem accurate. I'd appreciate if someone provides me a good accurate solution atleast upto 10^-6 precision. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Decompose your intersection area into polygons which are completely inside the circle, and [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) formed by a chord and a part of the arc. Use e.g. the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to compute the area of the polygoms, and the [segment area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area) for the segments. Compute these to whatever accuracy you want.

The decomposition will need to make *many* case distinctions. But choosing integration bounds and integration formulas isn't really any easier, in my opinion. There just is no simple way around all those case distinctions.

Comment: I'll have to find intersection point of circle and rectangle for that !!

Comment: @rishav: Yes. In fact you have to find all the points of intersection, and there might be up to 8 of them. Means solving 4 quadratic equations. See which edges intersect the circle at all. See which corners are inside and which are outside. Look at all the $2^8$ cases, see which of them can actually happen in real life, and come up with a decision tree to differentiate them.

Comment: As @MvG said, obtaining a general exact solution is above human forces... (and not intellectually very rewarding...) But if you need an approximate solution, this is very different : turn to a Monte Carlo method.

Answer (score 2):

This solution seems to be a special case of the other answer, but hopefully this will be easier to follow, though not as general.

First scale and translate such that the disk becomes the unit disk. (And rotate so the edges of the rectangle become parallel to the axes if needed)

The following function is the area of the intersection between the unit disk and a rectangle with corners $(0,0)$ and $(s,t)$, where $s>0, t>0$. Note that $s$ and $t$ could be any real numbers if we take the absolute values first
$$f(s,t)=\hspace{12cm}\text{ }\\\begin{cases}
 s\ t & s^2+t^2\leq 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+
\begin{cases}
 \sqrt{s^2-s^4}-\arccos(s) & s<1 \\
 0 & \text{else} \\
\end{cases} +
\begin{cases}
 \sqrt{t^2-t^4}-\arccos(t) & t<1 \\
 0 & \text{else} \\
\end{cases}
\right) & \text{else} \\
\end{cases}$$
The area of the intersection with any rectangle can be found by inclusion/exclusion in terms of the values of $f$ at each corner of that rectangle:

[image]
By testing all cases I found that the signs can be determined as follows:

1) Order the corners such that the first one has the smallest x and y coordinate and the last one has the biggest x and y coordinate. Those in between doesn't matter. I.e the pictured case will be either (c4, c1, c3, c2) or (c4, c3, c1, c2).

2) With the same ordering, write down for each corner whether it is in an odd or even quadrant. I.e the pictured case will be (E, E, O, O) or (E, O, E, O). If the corner is on an axis use the rules $(-x,0)\to E\quad,\quad(+x,0)\to O\quad,\quad(0, -y)\to E\quad,\quad(0, +y)\to O\quad,\quad(0,0)\to O,$

3) Count how many times the result from 2) changes letter, i.e. 1 or 3.

4) The signs for the f values in the chosen ordering are either
{1, -1, -1, 1} or {-1, 1, -1, 1} or {1, 1, 1, 1} or {-1, -1, 1, 1}
depending on whether 3) gave us 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Now multiply the f values by their sign, add up, and take $\text{abs}(\cdot )$. The final step is cancel the scaling that was done initially.

Answer (score -3):

You put the circle at the origin. The idea is to divide the rectangle 
into four rectangles, and then replace all rectangles 
that do not fall on the first quadrant by an equivalent rectangle, but located on the first quadrant. Then you deal with each
case according to the number of vertex inside the circle. At the end all areas are given in terms of a single function F(U,V)
that arises from the evaluation of the intersection area in the second case,
which is the case when only on vertex is inside the ellipse. Then you sum the four areas. The matlab code is:

A=2;        % Circle of radius 2 (or an ellipse of semi axes A,B)
B=2;
L_x=0.5;    % The  width
L_y=2.75;   % The height

x_1=0;     %bottom left corner (x_1,y_1)
y_1=-1;

%This function makes the calculation

int_area(x_1,y_1,L_x,L_y,A,B)

%The function definition
function [suma]=int_area(x_1,y_1,L_x,L_y,A,B)

x(1)=x_1;
y(1)=y_1;
% each one of the remaining vertex

x(2)=x(1);
y(2)=y(1)+L_y;
x(3)=x(1)+L_x;
y(3)=y(1)+L_y;
x(4)=x(1)+L_x;
y(4)=y(1);

% the center of the rectangle

x_m=x(1)+L_x/2;
y_m=y(1)+L_y/2;
suma=0;

% The original rectangle was divided in four rectangles
% with the new vertex coordinate of the closest vertex to the origin given by (a,b)
% according to the article http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/410103.pdf
% a (x- coordinate ) b( y coordinate)
% c new width
% d new height

for i=1:4

a(i)=max([ 0 (-1)^( 1/2*(i^2-i) )  *x_m - L_x/2 ]);

b(i)=max([ 0 (-1)^( 1/2*(i^2+i-2) )*y_m - L_y/2 ]);

c(i)=max([ 0 (-1)^( 1/2*(i^2-i) )  *x_m + L_x/2 - a(i) ]);

d(i)=max([ 0 (-1)^( 1/2*(i^2+i-2) )*y_m + L_y/2 - b(i) ]);

%in case the width and the height are different from 0 otherwise it contributes area zero
if (c(i) !=0 && d(i) !=0 )

%this is the ellipse equation evaluated on each vertex
eq_1=(a(i)/A)^2 + (b(i)/B)^2;
eq_2=(a(i)/A)^2 + ((b(i)+d(i))/B)^2;
eq_3=((a(i)+c(i))/A)^2 + ((b(i)+d(i))/B)^2;
eq_4=((a(i)+c(i))/A)^2 + (b(i)/B)^2;

% Area of intersection for each case according to the number of vertex inside the circle (or ellipse)
% S intersection area

if( eq_1 >=1  && eq_2 >=1 && eq_3 >=1 && eq_4 >=1)
S=0;        %case_I:  All vertex outside
end

if( eq_1 <1  && eq_2 >=1 && eq_3 >=1 && eq_4 >=1)
S=A*B/2* F(a(i)/A,b(i)/B);   %case_II: vertex I inside
end

if( eq_1 <1  && eq_2 >=1 && eq_3 >=1 && eq_4 <1)
S=A*B/2* (F(a(i)/A,b(i)/B)-F((a(i)+c(i))/A,b(i)/B));   %case_III: vertex 1 and 4 inside
end

if( eq_1 <1  && eq_2 <1 && eq_3 >=1 && eq_4 >=1)
S=A*B/2* (F(a(i)/A,b(i)/B)-F(a(i)/A,(b(i)+d(i))/B));   %case_IV: vertex 1 and 2 inside
end

if( eq_1 <1  && eq_2 <1 && eq_3 >=1 && eq_4 <1)
S=A*B/2* (F(a(i)/A,b(i)/B)-F((a(i)+c(i))/A,b(i)/B) - F(a(i)/A,(b(i)+d(i))/B));   %case_V: vertex 3 outside
end

if( eq_1 <1  && eq_2 <1 && eq_3 <1 && eq_4 <1)
S=c(i)*d(i);     %case_VI: all inside
end

else
S=0;    %in case the width or the height of the new rectangle is zero
end

suma=suma+S;   %the total area is suma
end

end

function [res] =  F (U,V)
  res=asin( sqrt(1-U^2)*sqrt(1-V^2) -U*V ) -U*sqrt(1-U^2)-V*sqrt(1-V^2)+2*U*V;
end

Note: for some reason some '*' (multiplication symbol) doesn't appear on the screen, but matlab uses it. All after the sign '%' is a comment

Best Regards

Ed.

Comment: I Forget the F(U,V)

Comment: While the OP *may* have been looking for a programming solution, many more Readers would benefit from a good description of the algorithm behind the implementation, i.e. an explanation of what the code is doing to get the area of intersection.

Comment: function [res] =  F (U,V)
  res=asin( sqrt(1-U^2)*sqrt(1-V^2) -U*V ) -U*sqrt(1-U^2)-V*sqrt(1-V^2) +2*U*V;
end

Comment: Sorry, here is a little explanation. You put the ellipse at the origin. The idea is to divide the rectangle in four rectangles, and then replace all rectangle that do not fall in the first quadrant by an equivalent rectangle, but located on the first quadrant. Then you deal with each case  according to the number of vertex inside the ellipse . To the end all areas are given in terms of the area of the first case, which is the case when only on vertex is inside the ellipse. Then you sum the four areas.

Comment: That is a helpful sketch.  I would put it into the beginning of your Answer to motivate the long code passage that follows (ellipse should be circle?).

Comment: The program is for an ellipse, the circle is a special case when A=B. So you can use it for the circle also.